# what data structure could be used to support foreign keys constraints

Tags: dictionary, go, data-structures, tree, big-o

Giving some context, I am implementing a fan-out (streaming) using gRPC, on the server every time a client connects,  I save the stream into a map and when the client disconnects I just remove it from the map so that I could keep the map updated with only "live" clients/connections.

So the initial map looks something like this:

```
key        value
client1    stream
client2    stream
client3    stream
```

The problem with this implementation is that if a client connects multiple times, only the last client (using the same `key id`) will receive the "broadcasted" message, since the map will overwrite the existing stream with the latest one from the client connecting, therefore I need to either use a unique key or to find a way to match, relate clients and connections.

I found easy to just switch the map and use as the key the connection ID, something like this

```
conn_id   client_id
conn1     client1
conn2     client2 \
conn3     client2  > 3 connections for client ID 2
conn4     client2 /
```

This works and helps to send a message to all connected clients, but makes things more complex if I would like to send a message to a specific client since I would need to range/traverse the full map to match the value with the desired client.

In an attempt to fix this, I switched back the map using the client_id, but instead of using the stream as the value, I am using a list of slices

```
key        value
client1   [stream, stream, stream]
client2   [stream]
client3   [stream, stream]
```

The problem persists since in order to send a message to all the clients the full map still needs to be traverse/range to get streams per client and send the message to each.

Therefore without using a database wondering what data structure could it be used following best practices regarding the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities)?

Mainly would like to find something that behaves similarly to database [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), probably having 2 maps one keeping all connections and other just keeping status or number of connections per client, for example:

```
key      value            client_id   # streams 
conn1    client1          client1     1   
conn2    client2          client2     3
conn3    client2
conn4    client2
```

But how to "atomically" remove a client from the `clients` map when there are no more connections from that client in the `connections` map.

This is a try but wondering if could be improved:

https://play.golang.org/p/VEoLsWh6dbJ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    clients := &sync.Map{}
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        clientID := fmt.Sprintf("client-%d", i%5)
        connID := fmt.Sprintf("conn-%d", i)
        client, ok := clients.LoadOrStore(clientID, connID)
        if ok {
            switch c := client.(type) {
            case string:
                client = []string{c, connID}
            case []string:
                client = append(client.([]string), connID)
            }
            clients.Store(clientID, client)
        }
    }

    list := func(k, v interface{}) bool {
        fmt.Printf("k: %+v v: %v\n", k, v)
        return true
    }

    clients.Range(list)

    // Get all connections
    broadcast := func(k, v interface{}) bool {
        fmt.Printf("To all connections from= %q\n", k)
        for _, v := range v.([]string) {
            fmt.Printf("msg to conn = %s\n", v)
        }
        return true
    }
    clients.Range(broadcast)
}
```

Here my try only using maps (easy to handle deletions) is slower but allocate fewer bytes:

https://play.golang.org/p/hz5uRX-VAvH

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    clients := &sync.Map{}
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        clientID := fmt.Sprintf("client-%d", i%5)
        connID := fmt.Sprintf("conn-%d", i)
        conns, ok := clients.Load(clientID)
        if ok {
            conns.(*sync.Map).Store(connID, i)
        } else {
            conns := &sync.Map{}
            conns.Store(connID, i)
            clients.Store(clientID, conns)
        }
    }

    list := func(k, v interface{}) bool {
        fmt.Printf("k: %v\n", k)
        listValue := func(j, l interface{}) bool {
            fmt.Printf("  j = %+v\n", j)
            return true
        }
        v.(*sync.Map).Range(listValue)
        return true
    }

    clients.Range(list)

    // Get all connections
    broadcast := func(k, v interface{}) bool {
        fmt.Printf("To all connections from= %q\n", k)
        listValue := func(j, l interface{}) bool {
            fmt.Printf("  msg to conn = %s -- %v\n", j, l)
            return true
        }
        v.(*sync.Map).Range(listValue)
        return true
    }
    clients.Range(broadcast)
}
```